# youtube-dl | OUTPUT parameters | remove just the appended "-id" tag

Tags: command-line, audio, video, youtube

`win10_HomePremium_x64
youtube-dl_16.05.10`

Since i'm using Windows, i've set an alias to use `youtube-dl.exe`

## ALIAS

- regedit > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor

  - new string value > "AutoRun"
  - set AutoRun's value to locate your `DOSKEY` alias's.
  - let's use `F:\Downloads\alias.cmd` as an example

## YOUTUBE-DL PARAMETERS

These are the `alias's` i've set using the `AutoRun` method.

> DOSKEY dl=youtube-dl.exe -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --embed-thumbnail $*
>   DOSKEY dlv=youtube-dl.exe -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -f mp4 $*

Then i'll use `cmd` to run one of the commands like so

> $ dlv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfC8UVKxHaE

## PROBLEM

The output of the file is just `(ext)s`.
What's wrong here?

#### NOTE

This in-correct filename output doesn't persist when using the parameters directly like so

> youtube-dl.exe -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -f mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfC8UVKxHaE

#### REFERENCE

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template

---

### FIX

- remove the quotes so within your alias.cmd (a method, as mentioned above). So, it's from this:

  - Take note that this example now has double-percentage symbol as @dstftw mentioned earlier to escape the syntax-format that Windows uses.

> DOSKEY dl=youtube-dl.exe -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --embed-thumbnail $*

to this...

> DOSKEY dl=youtube-dl.exe -o %%(title)s.%%(ext)s -x --audio-format mp3 --embed-thumbnail $*

Answer (score 1):

In batch file percent sign must be escaped by doubling:

```
DOSKEY dl=youtube-dl.exe -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --embed-thumbnail $*
DOSKEY dlv=youtube-dl.exe -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -f mp4 $*
```

Comment: That did get it to at least continue the download but now the filename is like so "^title^". That is with the two symbols pre / appended.

Answer (score 0):

### FIX

- remove the quotes so within your alias.cmd (a method, as mentioned above). So, it's from this:

  - Take note that this example now has double-percentage symbol as @dstftw mentioned earlier to escape the syntax-format that Windows uses.

> DOSKEY dl=youtube-dl.exe -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --embed-thumbnail $*

to this...

> DOSKEY dl=youtube-dl.exe -o %%(title)s.%%(ext)s -x --audio-format mp3 --embed-thumbnail $*